# How to use Virtual Private Server as Wordpress Image CDN

Tags: plugins, optimization, cdn, vps

I have 2 Private Server and 1 Shared hosting. 1 of my private server is not much in use, but my shared hosting is getting overloaded with images running wordpress.

I want to set my own CDN with my private server. I have already done below things :-

1. Create CDN subdomain of my site ( http://cdn.example.com with CNAME of my private server. )
2. Added CDN subdomain to my Private Server ( http://cdn.example.com )

I need help in below two things :-

1. Whenever image is uploaded , it instantly gets uploaded to my CDN server, that i have created in my VPS.
2. All images starts loading from my CDN server like :- http://cdn.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/1.jpg

For 2, I think, There is option to use ".htaccess" , but I am too much worried about point 1, how to make wordpress upload my file to CDN instead of local folder.

Please do not comment and reply with , Use CDN company like maxcdn etc., I can't afford to pay 1 extra cent to CDN at the moment.

I need solution strictly based on my requirement above.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I know you don't want CDN recommendations so forgive me, but you should just use Photon. Install WordPress Jetpack plugin, activate Photon. Totally free, takes 1 minute to setup

Comment: It is already there, but , what i am trying to achieve is host image out of my shared hosting box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds you want to do something similar as described in this article https://surpriseazwebservices.com/serve-images-from-sub-domain-in-wordpress/. You'll need to define your **upload_url_path** as your private server and also update the path of your existing images by running the following query in MySQL.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/','http://img.yoursite.com/');
```

The steps should all be documented in the link.